# FancyBox and Youtube API events

Tags: jquery, fancybox, youtube-api, fancybox-2, auto-close

I'm trying to fire an event once the youtube video that I'm playing into my fancybox is ended.

So I can close automatically the fancybox once the video is over.

I have the last fancybox version and I'm on the youtube API, sticking to exemples but it seems that ytplayer object is "undefined" and I can't make it work properly.

I have read a lot of stuffs on internet including this one, which seems to be good: [How make fancybox auto close when youtube video id done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541890/how-make-fancybox-auto-close-when-youtube-video-id-done)

This is the code I'm using: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn4FB/)

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'openEffect'  : 'none',
    'closeEffect' : 'none',
    'overlayOpacity' : 0.7,
    'helpers' : {
        media : {}
    },
    'afterLoad' :   function() {
        function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
            //alert(playerId);
            //alert(document.getElementById("myytplayer"));
            ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
            ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
        }

        function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
            //alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
            if (newState == 0){
                $.fancybox.close(true);
            }
        }
    }
});

// Launch fancyBox on first element
$(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');
```

If someone get this working, it would be awesome ! I just the video to close the fancybox once it finished !

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Please see following working code (you should use version 2 of fancybox.)

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/c5h9U/2/

```
// Fires whenever a player has finished loading
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// Fires when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    // Go to the next video after the current one is finished playing
    if (event.data === 0) {
        $.fancybox.close();
    }
}

// The API will call this function when the page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player API
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

    // Initialise the fancyBox after the DOM is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox")
            .attr('rel', 'gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect  : 'none',
                prevEffect  : 'none',
                padding     : 0,
                margin      : 50,
                beforeShow  : function() {
                    // Find the iframe ID
                    var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');

                    // Create video player object and add event listeners
                    var player = new YT.Player(id, {
                        events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    // Launch fancyBox on first element
    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');
    });

}
```

Comment: Maybe it is the tips and trick n°17, but it is still working and what I needed. So I say a big YES ! That helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @JFK Thanks for having me an advise. I'd put a reference when I copy an exact code from there, but I didn't because,

Comment: 1) It's directly from exact Fancybox's website, and question is about Fancybox.
2) I modified and merged into Brizoo's code.
I'm figuring out a manner of SOF, but it was my call by what I think right. You may be a keeper of all manner or not.., I hope you may be.

Comment: As well with a little modification it works with the onComplete event of the original FancyBox.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

- Testing "locally" (loading the file without going through
  http://localhost)
- Mixing Embed API (where you declare an iframe) with iframe API (where you declare a DIV and load some JS). The events only seem to work with the latter.
- ID on the DIV does not match ID on new YT.Player(...) call