# Close youtube video iframe after finished not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I have a youtube iframe video, and I want to close it when it ends.
This should be working, but it is not. The fancybox launches and the video displays correctly,  but none of the `console.log` appears. What am I doing wrong?

```
        $.fancybox({
          href: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/8CR-zM6jwD8?rel=0&autoplay=1",
          type: "iframe",
          beforeShow: function () {
              // Find the iframe ID
              var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');
              // Create video player object and add event listeners
              var player = new YT.Player(id, {
                  events: {
                      'onStateChange': function (event) {
                        console.log('onStateChange fired');
                          if (event.data === 0) {
                              console.log('ended');
                              $.fancybox.close();
                          } // if
                      } // onStateChange
                  } // events
              }); // YT.Player

              loadPage();
          }, // beforeShow
      }); // fancybox
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7r2ncdcr/)

Comment: Hi, Please make a fiddle

Comment: @P.Frank Done! Thank you man

Comment: Nice!  Please post your solution for other people who have the same issue

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880803/fancybox-and-youtube-api-events

Comment: @P.Frank I didn't solve it, I just reproduced the problem in the JSFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onStateChange` return an event, But is not possible access directly. you need `onReady` too. And i remove the end of your extension video `autoplay=1` and replace by `enablejsapi`. Work fine now

Please try:
http://jsfiddle.net/d6egj2sq/

Comment: Great! This works. 
Why does it need to have `onReady` event too? And what and why are `&enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque` parameters? What do they do and why do I need them for this to work?

Comment: If you add autoplay in url, your vidéos play auto because is a parameter but is not `YT.player` who play this. `onReady` get when your `YT.player ` completly charged videos. When is charged, the play function is activated. The parameter ¤enablejsapi` is for get api response.